# click() function in selenium not interactable. Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, kali-linux

I am writing my script to automate the form filling process for multiple websites.

So I basically targeted all fields using the xpath input type = xxx

But the strange thing is that the half-done script was perfect when running. it didnt show any errors. After a few days, I decided to run the script again to continue my work but the script shows an error now.

```
textfields = web.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="text"]')

for textfield in textfields:
  if textfield.get_attribute('value')!=Name:
  textfield.click()
  textfield.send_keys(Name)
```

The variable Name contains a string message of my name. So when the script is run, the error comes from the textfield.click() saying element not interactable. I use a loop because if there are any other fields with the input type text, it will just fill my name in. The strange thing is, when I use a VPN from VPNBook, this error does not show up. But the only issue when using the VPN is that I cannot submit the form as it detects me as spam as my IP is from other country.

I would like to know what is causing this error. Am i doing something wrong?

Note: I am using Kali Linux and Python.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML